# Symfony2 Twig extension RuntimeException

Tags: php, symfony

I'm buiding an application on symfony2 and need a new twig filter :

I created a folder Twig in my bundle and created there this file AppExtension.php :

```
namespace App\MyBundle\Twig;

use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_Filter_Method;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'left' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'leftFilter'),
        );
    }

    public function leftFilter($string, $start = 0, $length = 1)
    {
        $left = substr($string, $start, $length);
        return $left;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

and then I declared it in services.yml :

```
app.twig.app_extension:
    class: App\MyBundle\Twig\AppExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

But I get this RuntimeException:

> The autoloader expected class "App\MyBundle\Twig\AppExtension" to be defined in file ".../src/\App\MyBundle\Twig\AppExtension.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Can someone please tell me what I missed here ?

Comment: Are you sure there's no typo in your `namespace` *(corrected while posting)*? You can also try clearing symfony's cache and APC cache if you have.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help.
I checked and rechecked before and now you say that I checked and rechecked again - this it as it is.

Comment: I cleared cache by deleting content of cache folders (command cache:clear shows same error)
There must be an error but I can't see it !

Answer (score 1):

Use `<php?` instead `<?`.

That will solve the problem.